Unable to find safetest/vue after installing safetest
I'm trying to integrate safetest to test a Vue application but it's showing this error:

I tried installing safetest, and tried installing safetest/vue but I'm not getting the actual solution to the problem. Does safetest not have view embedded in it? I was following the repo, but got stuck at cannot find module safetest/vue
https://github.com/kolodny/safetest/tree/main/examples/vite-vue-ts

Add types for safetest package. npm i --save-dev @types/safetest.

npm error 404  '@types/safetest@*' is not in this registry. this was the response when I run it.
